# more then one lines in group by subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

i'd like to merge 2 selects into one.

first select (which i'd like to have like subquery) is

```
    select ait.ai_type_id, count(ai.envelope_id) 
    from oas_add_info_type ait 
    left join oas_case_additional_info ai 
        ON ai.type = ait.ai_type_id 
       AND ai.envelope_id = 4465 
    group by ait.ai_type_id 
    order by ait.ai_type_id
```

returns

```
    +------------+-----------------------+
    | ai_type_id | count(ai.envelope_id) |
    +------------+-----------------------+
    |          0 |                    17 |
    |          1 |                     0 |
    |          2 |                     0 |
    |          3 |                     0 |
    |          4 |                     0 |
    +------------+-----------------------+
```

and main select looks like:

```
    SELECT e.envelope_id, e.transmit_date, e.mcf, e.vehicle_action, e.manually_added 
    FROM oas_case_envelope e, oas_case_vehicle v, oas_users u, oas_companies c    WHERE e.envelope_id = v.envelope_id
      AND u.user_id = 1
      AND c.company_id = u.company_id
      AND ((e.envelope_name = '' AND Length(e.envelope_name) > 0) OR (v.vehicle_vin = '19XFB2F53CE105646' AND Length(v.vehicle_vin) > 0))    
    ORDER BY e.envelope_id DESC
```

and returns

```
    +-------------+---------------------+-----+----------------+----------------+
    | envelope_id | transmit_date       | mcf | vehicle_action | manually_added |
    +-------------+---------------------+-----+----------------+----------------+
    |        4465 | 2017-04-03 21:29:20 |   0 |              0 |              1 |
    |        4418 | 2017-01-14 11:37:46 |   0 |              0 |              0 |
    |        4384 | 2016-11-30 20:29:24 |   0 |              0 |              0 |
    |        4365 | 2016-10-31 21:59:37 |   0 |              0 |              0 |
    +-------------+---------------------+-----+----------------+----------------+
```

i need to put these two together

my best try is

```
    SELECT e.envelope_id, e.transmit_date, e.mcf, e.vehicle_action, e.manually_added, A.*
    FROM oas_case_envelope e
    JOIN oas_case_vehicle v ON e.envelope_id = v.envelope_id
    JOIN oas_users u ON u.user_id = 1
    JOIN  oas_companies c ON c.company_id = u.company_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM
           (select ait.ai_type_id, count(ai.type) 
            from oas_add_info_type ait 
            left join oas_case_additional_info ai ON ai.type = ait.ai_type_id AND ai.envelope_id = a.envelope_id 
            group by ait.ai_type_id 
            order by ait.ai_type_id)) as A ON a.envelope_id = e.envelope_id
    WHERE ((e.envelope_name = '' AND Length(e.envelope_name) > 0) OR (v.vehicle_vin = '19XFB2F53CE105646' AND Length(v.vehicle_vin) > 0))
```

and i receive

```
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

i'd appreciate any ideas.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Easy .... change this line

```
     order by ait.ai_type_id)) as A ON a.envelope_id = e.envelope_id
```

to

```
        order by ait.ai_type_id) as B) as A ON a.envelope_id = e.envelope_id
```

You have an extra derived table in there.

Answer (score 0):

/*Remove order by from inner query as sql doesn't allow order by in inner query and also give a alias for inner inner query (i gave it as g) at the end of bracket */

```
SELECT e.envelope_id, e.transmit_date, e.mcf, e.vehicle_action, e.manually_added, A.*
FROM oas_case_envelope e
JOIN oas_case_vehicle v ON e.envelope_id = v.envelope_id
JOIN oas_users u ON u.user_id = 1
JOIN  oas_companies c ON c.company_id = u.company_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM
       (select ait.ai_type_id, alt.envelope_id,count(ai.type) 
        from oas_add_info_type ait 
        left join oas_case_additional_info ai 
         ON ai.type = ait.ai_type_id AND ai.envelope_id = alt.envelope_id 
        group by ait.ai_type_id,alt.envelope_id
     ) as A ON a.envelope_id = e.envelope_id
WHERE ((e.envelope_name = '' AND Length(e.envelope_name) > 0) OR (v.vehicle_vin = '19XFB2F53CE105646' AND Length(v.vehicle_vin) > 0))
```

Thanks:-)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many depths in the subqueries:

```
SELECT e.envelope_id, e.transmit_date, e.mcf, e.vehicle_action, 
       e.manually_added, ait.ai_type_id, a.cnt
FROM oas_case_envelope e JOIN
     oas_case_vehicle v
     ON e.envelope_id = v.envelope_id JOIN
     oas_users u
     ON u.user_id = 1 JOIN
     oas_companies c
     ON c.company_id = u.company_id JOIN
     (select ai.envelope_id, ait.ai_type_id, count(ai.type) as cnt
      from oas_add_info_type ait left join 
           oas_case_additional_info ai 
           on ai.type = ait.ai_type_id AND ai.envelope_id = a.envelope_id 
      group by ait.ai_type_id, ai.envelope_id
     ) A 
     on a.envelope_id = e.envelope_id
WHERE ((e.envelope_name = '' AND Length(e.envelope_name) > 0) OR
      (v.vehicle_vin = '19XFB2F53CE105646' AND Length(v.vehicle_vin) > 0));
```

Notes:

- You don't need `select * from (<subquery>)` in the `from` clause.  You might have been thinking of work-around for `update` and `delete` syntax.
- Name the column in the subquery!
- The subquery does not have many columns, so list them explicitly (to avoid naming conflicts).
- You want to join on `envelope_id`.  That means the subquery needs to return that column.  I added it to the `group by`.